# Filter django query by day

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

I'm filtering a query by day of month.
The problem is that in my local machine everything is doing ok and i'm getting what is expected, but in production server the query set returns None.

Local

```
>>> Works.objects.filter(work_estimated_start_time__day=06)
>>> [<Works: 61: ns>]
>>> w[0].work_estimated_start_time
>>> datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 6, 15, 38, 37, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Server

```
>>> Works.objects.filter(work_estimated_start_time__day=06)
>>> []
>>> w = Works.objects.all()
>>> w[0].work_estimated_start_time
>>> datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 6, 15, 38, 2, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

The database data are pretty much the same.

Query from both environments (both are identical):

```
SELECT api_works.`work_id`, `api_works`.`work_central_id_id`, `api_works`.`work_user_id_id`, `api_works`.`work_driver_id_id`, `api_works`.`work_truck_id_id`, `api_works`.`work_estimated_start_time`, `api_works`.`work_start_time`, `api_works`.`work_end_time`, `api_works`.`work_first_pause_start_time`, `api_works`.`work_first_pause_end_time`, `api_works`.`work_second_pause_start_time`, `api_works`.`work_second_pause_end_time`, `api_works`.`work_creation_date`, `api_works`.`work_status`, `api_works`.`work_done`, `api_works`.`work_cancelation`, `api_works`.`work_enterprise_id_id`, `api_works`.`work_truck_type`
FROM `api_works`
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM CONVERT_TZ(`api_works`.`work_estimated_start_time`, 'UTC', Europe/Zurich)) = 6
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but I'm assuming you've made a copy of the production data on your local machine to ensure the queries will match?

Comment: can you print the query from both environments?  str(Works.objects.filter(work_estimated_start_time__day=06).query)

Comment: What database You use?

Comment: I'm using mysql. As soon as I can I will update the question with the queries in both environments. Thank you all

Comment: @marksweb yes.. my queries match

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli I've updated the questions with the query

Comment: OT: never use leading zero. Leading zero means octal literal. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/#id14

Comment: Show what is stored in DB

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup in server I have:


`>>> works = Works.objects.all()`
`>>> works`
`>>> [<Works: 39: ns>, <Works: 40: ns>]`
`>>>  for w in works:`
`>>>  ....:     print w.work_estimated_start_time`
`>>> ....:`
`>>> 2015-12-06 15:38:02+00:00`
`>>> 2015-12-06 15:45:54+00:00`

Comment: Show what is stored **directly** in DB

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup Here you have http://imgur.com/L33VCD3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL don't have native TimeZone operations in Django.

When **USE_TZ** is **True**, datetime fields are converted to the current time zone before filtering. To do it, You must have installed [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) and load the time zone tables with [mysql_tzinfo_to_sql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html).

Your production DB don't have [mysql_tzinfo_to_sql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html) loaded.

### Solution 1

Load [mysql_tzinfo_to_sql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html) on production

### Solution 2

Set **USE_TZ** to **False**

### Solution 3

Change DB to PostgreSQL. TZ support is out-of-the-box.

Look at [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4ced/6/0) MySQL without TZ support.

Comment: Thank you so much @TomaszJakubRup. This solves my problem. I didn't thought that MySQL was the problem. I've used solution 1, since I need to work with TZ and don't want to migrate to another Database System.